# What happened to Grand Nagus Zek's son, Krax?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

Early on in DS9, Zek is introduced in a story where he uses Quark to test his son Krax's worthiness to become Grand Nagus. Krax plots to kill Quark in order to seize the throne.

In one of the final episodes of DS9, though, Zek officially retires and appoints:

> Quark's brother, Rom

as the new Grand Nagus.

Is there any canon information that tells us what happens to Krax after this brief appearance or how he feels about being skipped over officially for the role of Grand Nagus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main Canon

There are no further mentions of Krax beyond his appearance in [DS9: The Nagus](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nagus_(episode)). He evidently proved himself unworthy as Zek's successor, even if he was his son. It would appear that the position isn't necessarily (or even especially) dynastic.

> **ZEK:** *I'm not interested in excuses.  Go back to the ship.  We'll be leaving here shortly.*
>
> **KRAX:** *Yes, Father.*
>
> Krax walks away, a defeated Ferengi.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: The Nagus - Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/411.txt)</sup></sub>

---

### EU Canon.

Krax makes [several more appearances](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Krax) in various Expanded Universe novels. Notably, in [Worlds of Deep Space Nine - Ferenginar: Satisfaction is Not Guaranteed](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Ferenginar:_Satisfaction_is_Not_Guaranteed) we learn that he became Rom's 'First Clerk', largely as a favour to Zek. This pays off when Krax is able to thwart a plot by Brunt to unseat Rom.

> *She then said words that she knew would upset Rom, but they needed to be said regardless. “We’re going to have to tell Krax.”
>
> Predictably, Rom winced. “Do we have to?”
>
> **“He’s your first clerk, Rom—and he’s got a good set of lobes on him. He is Zekkie’s son, after all.”**
>
> Rom then said exactly what Ishka thought he would say. “I know—and I remember what he tried to do to the last person Zek named his successor.”*